# Java output: can't write to subdirectory

Tags: java, path, output

How can I write to a file in a subfolder? Other answers on here said to use Paths, but no luck. In my code, for whichFileToSaveTo, if I remove "/Subfolder/" from it, my code works correctly and writes to the file. With "/Subfolder/", I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException.

I am using Windows 10. Thank you!

```java
/* whichFileToSaveTo = "/Subfolder/defaultSave.txt" */
FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(Paths.get(whichFileToSaveTo).toFile());    
for (JTextField j : times_JTextField_Array) {
    fw1.write(j.getText() + "\n");
}
fw1.close();
```

Comment: Does that subfolder already exist, and, if not, do you first create it in your Java code?

Comment: The subfolder exists, but I created it manually rather than in my code. The same folder contains my MainProgram.java as well as Subfolder.

Comment: It is irrelevant, where your java-file is located. You need to know the directory from which the java process is started. Is this the same? If not, there is your mistake, since relative pathes will start in this "execution folder".

Comment: Yes, same directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved. The solution was to use absolute path:

`FileWriter fw1=new FileWriter(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath() + whichFileToSaveTo);`

Answer (score 0):

You are giving a relative path to save the file as follows :

whichFileToSaveTo = "/Subfolder/defaultSave.txt";

This may or may not work depending on your current working directory. Try to use absolute paths. Since, the program is throwing a FileNotFoundException, it is certain that the path provided is wrong.

Comment: Another try would be to omit the first ```/```

Comment: I had tried omitting the first / before; still didn't work.